# Is Winpcap captures and modifys data?

Tags: windows, networking, libpcap, winpcap

I am working on project that can capture the data passed from the user to the network in the same machine and modify its contents.

But I don't know if Winpcap can only capture or can also modify the data???

I hope my question was so obvious for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture. You can modify what you capture, but that doesn't affect what goes through the network stack: only what you have in your own sniffing process. You can't filter packets out either.

Comment: I'm developing a VPN project, as you know, VPN encapsulates packets (IP, TCP/UDP, Data) into a new packet with compression and encryption techniques.
So, can Winpcap helps me in this project?

Comment: No, I don't know anything about your project. I only know what you asked above, and I answered that.